# Casting "div" in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Is there a way to cast a programmatically created `<DIV>` in order to get the property innerHtml?

```
 HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

How can i get `div.innerHTML` ?

Comment: if you want to get the innerHTML i think you are reffering to client side programming, using JavaScript.

Comment: hm , but i want it in code behind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this not work:

```
div.InnerHtml = "<b>hello</b>";
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx)